# Quadratic optimization with box constraints, continuity of the maximizer.

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, optimization

Consider

$$x^*(c)= \begin{cases}\displaystyle\operatorname{argmax}_{{x}} &x^{\top}Ax+b^{\top}x \\[12pt] 
  \text{ subject to } & -c \le x \le c   \end{cases}  $$

where $A$ is a negative-definite matrix and $b$ and $c$ are vectors of appropriate size.
I would like to prove that $x^*(c)$ is continuous in $c$. Is this a known result?